# Supersonic flow of non-compressible fluids

Tags: nozzle, supersonic, acceleration

Will the non-compressible fluids, travelling at Mach 1, at the throat of a CD nozzle, accelerate after they leave the throat?

Comment: Relevance to space exploration?

Comment: If you assume incompressibility, the speed of sound is infinite, so the concept of Mach 1 is meaningless.  Supersonic flow is and must be compressible flow.

Comment: @Tristan "the speed of sound is infinite" - well say a factor of four or five higher than in air. I'm interested though, did you mean something else that had the same end result?

Comment: @Organic Marble. Though not directly related to space exploration, it originated from related study. I am trying to understand rockets. In the process came to know that compressible hot gases accelerate when they pass the throat at M1. While I failed to understand why so, this thought came to my mind. I am sorry if this is a wrong place to post such questions. can you suggest any site where I can post many other related technical queries? Thanks.

Comment: I think while maybe seen as purely academic, it is still an interesting question. Incompressibble fluids have a 'sound-speed' analogon, which is $c=\sqrt{gH}$ for the case of the incompressible shallow-water equations, and of course it can be $v>c$. I can try later to have a look at the math, if no one beats me to it.

Comment: @ AtmosphericPrisonEscape. Thank you so much. At the outset, the real question is "WHY" do the exhaust gases accelerate (in case of rocket engine) if they cross the throat at M > / = 1? I thought may be the in-compressible fluids may not be accelerating, hence the question. By the way, I am looking for an answer without mathematical equations. Many times people give answers, e.g., which suggest:  "An apple falls down because Newton's law says so, as per his 'xyz" equation. Hope you get what I am saying. Laws are documented observations. I am looking for the "WHY".

Comment: @Puffin The speed of a low amplitude pressure wave is $\sqrt{\frac{dP}{d\rho}}$. In a perfectly incompressible medium, $\rho$ is constant, meaning you divide by zero.  "Incompressible" media like water, steel, etc., are still just a little bit compressible, hence the finite speed of sound.

Comment: @Niranjan "Why" type explanations lend themselves to oversimplifications, mischaracterizations, and confusion between cause and effect (see, for example, the classic Bernoulli misconceptions about how airfoils generate lift)

Comment: @Tristan. Agreed. in fact, a few minutes back I was reading exactly the same topic of explanation about airfoil lift using Bernoulli's theorem. Despite this, explaining the "why" and/or How, using some equations/laws, which in themselves are documented output of observations of the events, does not help understand the issue. Its a vicious circle. Anyway, if it is so, be it so..Thanks for valuable time.